# epoch in C++ using mktime

Tags: c++, date, datetime

I was reading the following: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime

Which in particular says:

> Converts local calendar time to a time since epoch as a time_t object.

I has assumed this epoch is the unix epoch (1970 01 01), but from the following program

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tm example = {00, 00, 00, 01, 12, 69};
    std::cout << std::mktime(&example) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output

> 0

This is telling me that the epoch is at 00:00:00 on 1st December 1969.
Is the epoch implementation defined, or have I some other fundamental misunderstanding?

Comment: The `epoch` is not defined by the `C++` standard. `POSIX` defines it as `1970 01 01` so `unix/linux` machines conform to that.

Comment: I ran this on a unix box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)

`tm_mon` is defined as month since January [0,11] which makes your 12 months given to `std::tm` to December + 1 month, so January 1970.

As an example, the year 1968 with 24 months returns 0 as well:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::tm example;
  example.tm_sec = 0;
  example.tm_min = 0;
  example.tm_hour = 0;
  example.tm_year = 68;
  example.tm_mon = 24;
  example.tm_mday = 1;

  std::cout << std::mktime(&example) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

(or `-3600` because of DST)

Answer (score 3):

For a modern, less error prone way of doing this, here's a [free, open-source C++11/14/17 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to do the same thing, avoiding the error-prone, thread-unsafe C API.

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    sys_seconds t = sys_days{1_d/dec/1969};
    std::cout << t.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
-2678400s
```